# How to instantiate objects that use setInterval in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, setinterval, instantiation

I am trying to define a function in javaScript that starts a setInterval.
Here is a very simple example:

var myApp = {};

```
myApp.test = function(name, start) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = start;
    selbst = this;
    this.timerId = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Interval for :' + selbst.name);
        selbst.value++;
        console.log('Name: ' + selbst.name + ', new value: ' + se`enter code here`lbst.value);
        selbst.start++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

If I instantiate one object this works perfect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new myApp.test('Test1', 0);
});
```

However, when I define two objects

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new myApp.test('Test1', 0);
    new myApp.test('Test2', 100);
});
```

only the second object has the setInterval started!  Why is that?  I wan that both objects, that are referring to the same class, have their own Interval.
Why is the second setInterval overriding the first?  I am using class fields, they should be independent!

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, you have `selbst` variable defined globally, so on each `test` method call, `selbst` will always refer to the last `myApp` object instance. Defining `selbst` locally should do the job:

```
var selbst = this;
```

Comment: Man, I was blind!  Thank you for the quick answwer!